# Can we convert flutter code into kivymd code?

Tags: flutter, kivymd

I want to make a shopping-like app. I have found some flutter code so I was just wondering that is it possible to convert flutter code into kivymd code ?

Comment: See [ask] to improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, maybe nobody has done it before but it is possible, someone could create a function or algorithm that may be capable to do so, for example, creating the equivalent code into equivalent syntax for kivymd.

If you could share parts of the code then I can help you converting the code from flutter to the equivalent in kivymd, if you can add images it will be great